# Method to generate an array of datetimes in python

Tags: python, datetime, date-range

I am trying to come up with a method to generate a set of timestamps 15 minutes every hours, 8 hours per day for the last month. My approach is top-down, first generate the days and then use these candidates to generate 8 children-timestamps for every day and then finally generate 4 grandchildren-timestamps for every hour.

```
collection = []
numdays = 10
numHours = 4
numMinutes = 5

base = datetime.datetime.today()
datelist = [base - datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, numdays)]
hourList = [date - datetime.timedelta(hours=x) for date in datelist]
minuteList = [hour - datetime.timedelta(minutes=numMinutes) for hour in hourList]
```

Is there a more elegant substructure to thinking about this?

Comment: `date in xrange(datelist)` is returning you a list of numbers, not date objects

Comment: Please fix your code first, it has multiple errors in it.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs @cricket_007, I have incorporated your comments into the code.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
first = datetime(2016, 8, 1, 8, 0, 0)
dates = [first]
for days in range(1, 31): # How many days.
  for _ in range(8 * 4): # 8 hours, 4x 15 min intervals per hour
    dates.append(dates[-1] + timedelta(minutes = 15))
  dates.append(dates[0] + timedelta(days = days))
```

Answer (score 1):

To generate a list of datetime with a fixed delta do the following (example for generating a list of length 8 * 4 with interval of 15 minutes, which addresses part of the question):

`

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

first = datetime(2016, 8, 1, 8, 0, 0)
delta = timedelta(minutes = 15)
dates = (first + delta * x for x in range(8 * 4))
```

`

`dates` is a generator object.  To print the dates use `print(list(dates))`